# Highlight HTML syntax inside a string?

Tags: visual-studio-code, syntax-highlighting, template-strings

Is there a way (plugin, option, or tip and trick) to highlight HTML syntax in a JS string?

My document is a `.js` file, in which I use strings containing HTML code. Is it possible to highlight HTML syntaxe inside these strings?

[image]

Comment: Welcome to SO. I took the liberty to rephrase your question so that is more easily readable.

Comment: ok thank, english are not my natal language sorry for mistake.And stackflow delete some work like HI !

Comment: No problem :) And I would not call it a mistake. SO tries to focus on the questions and greetings, thanks etc. are considered irrelevant to the question ([fluff](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260776/should-i-remove-fluff-when-editing-questions)).

Answer (score 47, accepted):

You can use the extension [**es6-string-html**](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Tobermory.es6-string-html)

**Note**: You need to add a comment with the language in front of the multiline string

[image: Before and After]

Comment: Sadly it doesn't appear to help with intilisense :(

Comment: intilisense is run by ts-server and its not process any strings

Answer (score 10):

The extension that you suggested requires that you prefix your strings with a comment like `/*html*/` or `html`. I'm working with Angular, and I didn't want to go through all my templates to prefix them, so I found this extension that does it automatically without prefixes:

https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=natewallace.angular2-inline

It is included in the Angular Essentials package by John Papa:

https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=johnpapa.angular-essentials

Comment: perfect! it works for any js file, not only for Angular :)

Answer (score 0):

For **Vue** try **Vue Inline Template**:

https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=faisalhakim47.vue-inline-template

Answer (score 0):

You can try the extension **leet-html**. It works fine, without any prefix or comment to add, and not related to any framework.

[image]